# ParallelTable and expensive functions

Tags: list-manipulation, parallelization

I would like to build up a 2D-Table using [`ParallelTable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelTable.html) as follows

```
tab = Flatten[ParallelTable[{i,j,f[i,j]},{i,1,ni},{j,1,nj}],1];
```

This instruction works perfectly. However, I would like to speed it up. Indeed, the function `f[i,j]` is defined as `f[i_,j_] := f1[i] f2[i,j]`

The particularity here is that `f1[i]` is expensive to compute, so that I would like to compute it only one time for each `i`.

How would it be possible to tune the `ParallelTable` so that `f1[i]` is only evaluated when it has never been done before ? A kind of *nested* `ParallelTable` ? Using *memoization* ? (As the construction of the table remains long, it is key for me to necessarily use parallelized evaluations on multiples cores)

Comment: I "think", don't have time to try right now, f[i_]:=f[i]=body of f to memoize and SetSharedFunction[f] will do what you want.  The down values of f[i] should be shared.  Not really sure who wins if two kernels try to set f[1] at the same time.  I assume first wins and both would calculate the same value unless you're doing some monte-carlo?

Comment: Indeed, my functions are completely deterministic, so that `f[1]` has only value and I don't care which kernel calculates it and when. I will try your approach. Otherwise, I thought I might proceed manually and define a function `listf[i_] := v = f1[i]; Table[{v f2[i,j]},{j,1,nj}]` and then use `ParallelTable[{i,j,listf[i]},{i,1,ni}]` (The list structure is not good, but this is the idea.) However, it might not be as fast as expected.

Comment: @Ymareth Your solution worked ! I defined the expensive function `f1` using the *recurrence* syntax `f1[i_] := f1[i] = ...` and added the instruction `SetSharedFunction[f1]`. Using the instruction `Print[$KernelID]`, I also checked that the evaluations were correctly parallelized. I divided by a factor of 50 my computation time... Should I/you write an answer to my question, or are these comments enough ?

Comment: I'll try to write a proper answer in next few days, unless someone beats me to it - thanks :).